# working with console writeline c#

Tags: c#

I need to output the value of `d` using the same `Console.WriteLine`. But i am only getting *Result* not the value of `d` in output. In what way i can achieve this?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a;
            int b;
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the first Digit");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Second Digit");
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int d = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine("Result",(d));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
Console.WriteLine("Result {0}", d);
```

You are using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx).

UPDATE

If you look at the link above, you can read how it works. In short, first you specify the formatting, where {0} references the first value of the param object-array, {1} references the second value of the param object-array, etc. After the format, you give the objects to use.

So in your case, you need a single value, which means two arguments, a format, and a value. Hence "Result {0}" with d, which will become (when for example d=10) "Result 10".

Note: also removed the unnecessary parenthesis.

Comment: Not necessary, but copied them from the OP's question.

Comment: @Maarten You can add a link to `string.Format` MSDN doc page :)

Comment: @Geek you should accept this as the answer since it helped you with your question. You can accept a answer by clicking the tick next to the vote buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Console.WriteLine("Result {0}", d);
```